# Why is 1st for loop isn't getting executed in Code blocks?

Tags: c, norm

This is a program to find norm of a matrix. I am using Code Blocks to write codes. The 1st for loop in this code which is used to fill the matrix doesn't get executed in Code Blocks but gets executed in a online c compiler. Why is this happening?

### ///find the norm of a matrix

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
void main()
{
    short int r,c;

    register short int i,j;

    //fill matrix
    printf("\nENTER MATRIX DIMENSION");
    printf("\nROWS: ");
    scanf(" %d",&r);
    printf("COLUMNS: ");
    scanf(" %d",&c);

    printf("\ncheck1");

    --r; --c;
    printf("\ncheck2");
    float mat[r][c],sum,norm;

    printf("\ncheck3");

    //1st for loop:fill array                  
    for(i=0 ;i<= r ;i++)
    {
        for(j=0 ;j<= c ;j++)
        {
            printf(" \nELEMENT %d x %d: ",i,j);
            scanf(" %f",&mat[i][j]);
        }
    }

 printf("\ncheck4");
 
    //finding norm
    sum = 0;
     for(i=0;i<=r;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<=c;j++)
        {
            sum = sum + pow(mat[i][j],2);
        }
    }

    norm = pow(sum,0.5);
    printf("\n\nNORM: %f",norm);
}
```

Comment: `scanf(" %d",&r);` The `"%d"` tells `scanf` to read an `int` but you pass a pointer to a `short int`.

Comment: when compiling, always enable the warnings, then fix those warnings.  ( for `gcc`, at a minimum use: -Wall -Wextra -Wconverson -pedantic -std=gnu11` )  Note: other compilers use different options to produce the same results.

Comment: regarding; `void main()`  Per the C standard, there are only two valid signatures for `main()`  They are: `int main( void )`  and `int main( int argc, char *argv[] )`

Comment: suggest printing the values read for `r` and `c`

Comment: Talking about `for(i=0 ;i<= r ;i++)` and `for(j=0;j<=c;j++)` there's a mistake: in `mat[r][c]` indexes can vary from 0 to `r-1` and from 0 and `c-1`. they should be `for(i=0 ;i<r ;i++)` and `for(j=0;j<c;j++)`.

Comment: Get rid of `--r; --c;` and change `i<=r` etc to `i<r`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code is correct but the for loop is not executing because the condition:

```
for(i=0;i<=r;i++)
```

`i<=r`   is getting false.

Why?
Because garbage value is being stored in your variable `r` and `c`.

*You are using format specifier **`%d`** which is for int.
The Format specifier for short is **%hd**.*
*Just use **`%hd`** and everything will work fine.*